# How can I hide all content from a specified user?

Tags: support, users, display-names

Is it possible to hide all of the posts from a specific user on Stack Overflow? Or perhaps just to hide the user name?

There is nothing wrong about this user, but certain user names just look disgusting to me. It feels like being forced to watch porn.

Comment: Age-old mother meta dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users

Comment: its a little bit difference. some keyword (and i just realize them) make me feels disgusting
I cant report it because those word is totally general for most of people.
There is nothing to do with who they are and what they say.
maybe customer script is the ways to go.

Comment: Um...I'm really not sure what the word is that's causing you offense (and I'd recommend that you not repeat it), but have you tried raising a moderator flag?  Mods are meant to remove names which are offensive, since this is a mostly professional environment anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but im pretty sure the user name is ok.
it will be nice to have the option but i can always use a customer script to filter them out.

Comment: So you're saying that you just don't *like* their username?  If that's the case then yeah, a userscript would be the best route.

Comment: not sure why you want to be doing this.. But there is a custom userscript that comes close to what you want [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/3105/hide-all-pointless-user-data-gravatar-badges-and-reputation). You could check if you can hide the username as well..

Comment: >Makoto In other word, yes.

>suraj it doesnt hide user name from comments, i think i just modify it to fit my requirement.

Comment: Alright.. heads up though, it will hide content for _all users_..Dont know if hiding names in comments is wise.. I am unclear on your usecase because ASAIK there is a world of difference between _not liking a username_ and _being forced to watch porn_.

Comment: Is that a troll? I mean do you use a pornsite a search engine? Or you have to check for the last production, every time you see a porn star reference? It's hard for me to understand exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: OK I think i use the wrong word. the username had no relation to anything porn.
but the feeling is true, just like some people can not handel some insect. I cannot handel with some keyword.
anyway, i modified a little bit from the below script to remove only the username i needed and it works.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script

still, a native option is much better because i can still recongnize it if the loding time is slow.

Comment: I totally agree with you! I would love to never see again some cocky, rude and disgusting users of S.O.

Answer (score 10):

The system does not have any features that would allow you to do this.

The *reason* why it doesn't is because the focus here is on *content*, not on users. You can read the posts here and learn useful things without ever caring about the users' names. It's the same reason why you cannot "follow" another user or have a private conversation with another user. This isn't a social-networking site, so we don't need to have follow, block, and poke options.

If you come across a user name that is offensive, please flag one of their posts for moderator attention and explain your concerns. We will investigate and can change user names that are inappropriate. The site's ["Be Nice" policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) applies both to posts *and* user names. (The only place where we allow a bit of leeway is in the user's "about me" section, on their profile page. That's because you have to *go to* someone's profile in order to see it, and you aren't required to view someone's profile as part of your ordinary interaction with the site. Still, if you push our limits too far, we will push back.)

If you are just offended by normal everyday words, then you might consider just *not* being offended. Growing a thicker skin can make life a lot easier and more pleasant.

Comment: "be nice" is a good policy but im pretty confident its being abused.
will an option to display user_id instead of username a valid suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure who is abusing it. Yes, displaying user IDs instead of names would be a valid suggestion, but I don't expect it to be implemented. If a user name is offensive or causing harm, then we need to know about it so we can take care of it---not just for you, but everyone that uses the site.

Comment: I believe the purpose of the username is to identify a user.
but I also know that username's purpose is to "force a discusion"
the best i can do is to ignore it, and it will be a lot better if the system can help.
they already win if anyone try to "take care" of them
I believe providing an option to show user_id instead of username will benfit quite a lot of user.

Comment: And they don't win if we re design how we display ALL users because of how a couple of bad apples are using the system?@user753226

Comment: in the point of my view, yes.
but the point is, there is no "absolute true" anywhere.
by letting user choose what they need, we can further loosen the rule and create a more free world.
one is free to do something should also free to reject something.